# strtotime from while variable show wrong result

Tags: php

i want to query less than 1 month from below data

[image]

```html
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

// cek koneksi
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Koneksi Database Gagal : '.$mysqli->connect_error);
}
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT tgl_exp FROM i_test ")
 or die('Ada kesalahan pada query tampil Data Barang: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "$data[tgl_exp]<br>";                                          
}

$newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime($data)));
echo $newdate;
```

but why the result is wrong like picture below?

[image]

please give me the clue, thank you for the help

Comment: You are running `strtotime` on `$data`, which is an array, you need to run it on the elements within.

Comment: The loop ends when `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` can't fetch any more rows, and returns `false`. So `$data == false` after the loop is done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `strtotime()` inside the loop, when `$data` contains a valid row. After the loop is done, `$data` is empty.

And the argument has to be `$data['tgl_exp']`. `$data` is the whole row, which is an array.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

// cek koneksi
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Koneksi Database Gagal : '.$mysqli->connect_error);
}
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT tgl_exp FROM i_test ")
 or die('Ada kesalahan pada query tampil Data Barang: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));

 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "$data[tgl_exp]<br>";
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime($data['tgl_exp'])));
    echo $newdate . '<br>';                         
}

$newdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime($data)));
echo $newdate;
```